# How to assing routes to an array of widget screens?

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, navigation, bloc

i have the following routes in my main

```
routes: {
        '/sign-in': (context) => BlocProvider(
              lazy: false,
              create: (_) => AuthCubit(),
              child: const LandingPage(),
            ),
        '/home': (context) => const HomeLandingPage(),
        '/sign-up': (context) => const SignUpLandingPage(),
        '/language-selection': (context) => const SelectionLanguageScreen(),
        '/camera-page': (context) => CameraPage(),
        '/web-add-page': (context) => const WebAddPage()
      },
```

i'm having issues implementing Routes to my `WebAddPage()` because `WebAddPage()` is a widget that is threated as a screen.

```
 final screens  = [  //screens is a List<Widget>
      const WebAddPage(),
      const WebUpdateProducts(),
      const WebUpdateCategories(),
      const WebUpdateStores(),
      const WebUpdateUsers()
    ];
```

i'm not using `Navigator.push` because i'm not changing to a new screen i'm just changing widgets. is there a way the implement the Routes system to this array. i also need the url path to matches the route.

`Navigator.push` apparently didn't work, also adding the key word of the route change the type of the `List<Widget>` to a `List<object>` but because im implementing the screens into a child i can't use the `List<object>` because the type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'

Comment: You're question is not enough detailed, to get better responses you might provide more part of your code as for example how you're currently traveling through your one page.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the package flutter autoroute: https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route that allows you to easily setup your project around routes, nested routes architecture and paths.

However if you still want to continue with your architecture, then you cannot switch your routes while using a one page changing Widget dynamically from an index.

So my advice is to use autoroute and if you need redirections, look also at Route Guards.

Answer (score -2):

I think it can help you

```
final List<Widget> pages = const [
    HomePage(),
    SearchPage(),
    NotificationsPage(),
    SettingPage()   ];

 @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
        _title,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
      )),
      body: pages[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(color: ColorManager.lightGray, spreadRadius: 0.5)
          ],
        ),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          selectedItemColor: ColorManager.primary,
          unselectedItemColor: ColorManager.gray,
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          onTap: onTap,
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: AppStrings.home),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search), label: AppStrings.search),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
                label: AppStrings.notification),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: AppStrings.setting),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );   }
```

Comment: i'm working with this method, i need to implement routes while using this metod of changing screens

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).